# JWT-TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, payload

hello i am creating token validation (JWT) and this error came up here is the code 
of JWT signing token:

```
 if (user) {
      const payload = user._id
        console.log(payload)

        console.log(process.env.SECRET)
        const token = jwt.sign({id :payload}, process.env.SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 10
        })

        console.log(token)
     res.cookie('token', token, {
            httpOnly: true
        });
```

and verifying it (in middleware)

```
const token = req.body.token ||
    req.query.token ||
    req.headers['x-access-token'] ||
    req.cookies.token;

if (!token) {
   res.status(401).send({auth: false})
}
else{
jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err){ 
        res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
    })
} 

    req.userId = decoded.id

    next()
  })

}
```

i do not know the problem, i think i did everything according to docs but this error still shows up if anyone knows the solving for this problem i would be glad if i hear it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `jwt.verify` fails, you're trying to access `decoded.id` which does not exist. So issue a `return` inside `if(err)` otherwise the code will continue, calling `next` & trying to access `decoded.id`, triggering an error.

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            })
        }

        req.userId = decoded.id

        next()
})
```

Comment: but since i am creating validation on main page how should i determine if user is authenticated or not?

Comment: By using cookies. I thought that was a authentication middleware that you build. Use that as a middleware for every route you need authenticated.

Comment: i am doing so but this middleware is for default route and i want to determine whether user is authenticated or not to (for example) display his profile pic on main page, before i was using middleware for '/profile' route and redirecting user to main page if there was no token (or session)  but how can i do it when main page is profile page too if token exists?

Comment: you can use the middleware anywhere you want, in your main page, or your profile page. I'm not sure I follow what you want to achieve.

Comment: so if we take facebook as an example facebook has main page where you can authenticate on main page 'facebook.com/' and if you are authenticated Facebook code displays your timeline still on default route 'facebook.com/' i am doing same thing but main page contains other content, if user is not authenticated main page is as usual but if user is authenticated for example profile picture and other features is added on main page. and when i am sending {auth: false} if token does not exist i think it is bad practice, since attacker can change it in client side, so i want best practice to determine

Comment: whether user is authenticated or not and make decisions on that boolean

Comment: if you don't understand it properly we can continue talking in chat